# Are there linguistic arguments for the claim that "Odi et amo" in Catullus (LXXXV) cannot be simply translated as 'I hate and I love'?

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, verbs, semantics, catullus

On the basis of literary arguments, Arkins (2011) ["The meaning of *Odi et amo* in Catullus 85](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2041-5370.2011.00015.x) came to the interesting conclusion that *Odi et amo* in the following famous poem by Catullus (LXXXV) cannot be simply translated as "I hate and I love" but rather as "I loathe her, I lust for her". His conclusion is indeed quite original and provocative if one considers the typical translations of this poem (e.g., for a selection of different translations, see Rose (2019) [*Odi et amo*: A brief history in translation](https://camws.org/filebrowser/download/1419)).

> Odi et amo. Quare id faciam fortasse requiris.
> Nescio sed fieri sentio et excrucior.

My specific **linguistic** question here is the following one: is it exceptional to find allegedly stative verbs like *odisse* and *amare* as reassumed by the agentive verbal phrase *facere id*? I'm asking this since in many languages it is often the case that stative verbs cannot be reassumed by the non-stative agentive verbal expression *facere id* 'to do it' (which is NOT the same as the grammaticalized expression 'to do so'  in English). For example, the following Spanish and Catalan translations sound quite odd: Sp. “Odio y amo. ¿Por qué *lo hago*? (tal vez me preguntas…)” // Cat. “Odio i estimo. Per què *ho faig*? (tal vegada em preguntes…)”. Could you please let me know if the same happens in your native language? For example, TKR, in his comment below, also points out a similar semantic clash in Hebrew.

Here is some very sketchy linguistic background on so-called ["psychological verbs"](https://www.thoughtco.com/psych-verb-definition-1691550). There is a typical tripartite classification of these verbs according to the syntactic function (and case, in Latin) of the experiencer argument: (I) nominative subject (*timere*-verbs), (II) accusative direct object (*terrere*-verbs) and (III) dative indirect object (*placere*-verbs). Typically, the first class is semantically analyzed as lacking an event, i.e., they are **stative** predicates. For example, see page 3 of Filip's (1996) work where you'll find the following statement: "Psychological predicates of the *fear* type are stative" ([Filip 1996](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Efilip/Filip.Psychverbs.1996.pdf)) NB: *amare*/'to love' and *odisse*/'to hate' are also assumed to belong to the *timere*/'to fear'-type/class, the verbs whose experiencer argument is the subject.

Following TKR's suggestion below, it would be interesting to find other similar contexts where psychological predicates of the 1st class above (verbs whose experiencer argument is the subject of the clause: e.g., *amare*, *odisse*, *timere*, etc.) are reassumed by *facere id*. Could you provide us with some attested examples of this linguistic phenomenon?

It is also VERY important to note that *faciam* and *requiris* are agentive predicates, compared to the verbs of the second verse, which are ALL non-agentive: *nescio*, *fieri*, *sentio*, and *excrucior*. So, in line with this distribution of agentive vs. non-agentive verbs in the 1st and 2nd verses, respectively, **I was wondering if the use of *faciam id* to reassume *odi* and *amo* could be taken as a linguistic argument for extending the basic/lexical meaning of *odisse* and *amare* from a stative to a more agentive interpretation**. If that were the case, this could also be taken as a non-subjective argument for Arkins's (2011) conclusion above in the sense that the translations of *odi* and *amo* in this poem should ideally incorporate a more agentive-like component, which is typically missing in 'I hate' and 'I love', respectively. Notice then that such an ingredient of agentivity would in turn nicely correspond more with the **physical** component argued for by Arkins (see the first link above) and less with the merely psychological lexical/basic meaning of these verbs.

---

It is also worth pointing out that a relevant **[chiasmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)** structure has been said to be involved in this famous poem: cf. *odi et amo* -- *excrucior*; *faciam* -- (*sentio*) *fieri*; *requiris* -- *nescio* (alternatively, *odi* -- *excrucior*; *amo* -- *sentio*; *faciam* -- *fieri*; *requiris* -- *nescio*). In the light of the present question, note that this stylistic fact can also be put in correspondence with the linguistic/semantic contrast I have alluded to above: i.e. more agentive verbs (1st verse) -- non-agentive verbs (2nd verse).

Comment: Interesting question. Do you know if there are other such cases in Latin? Just as another data point, Hebrew (my first language) would also disallow *do it* in this context. I wonder about Greek; my guess is that ποιέω/πράττω would be odd and πάσχω would be preferred, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Many thanks, TKR, for your comment on Hebrew and for your suggestion about the need of trying to obtain more similar cases of this phenomenon in Latin. I've just reformulated my question above accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In English any verb which syntactically takes a subject can be reassumed by “do”. “I hate cod but she doesn’t” is perfectly natural even though no actual *doing* is involved.

Indeed one of the puzzles of modern Latin languages is that they cannot easily resume verbs. Either they just omit the verb altogether (pero ella no?) or they have to change construction. Come to think of it, Polish also resumes by omission (a ona nie).

The question is whether the modern Latin re-division of the landscape, which you describe, was already present in Latin (perhaps depending on register) or whether, like the addition of definite and indefinite articles, the aorist-perfect distinction and the need for an active past participle, it was added later.

Comment: Yes, in Romance languages like Catalan or Spanish, you cannot use _facere id_ 'to do it' (e.g., Cat. 'fer-ho' and Sp. 'hacerlo') to reassume a previous stative verb. Cf. the well-formedness of Cat. "La Maria aprèn llatí i en Pau també ho fa" (lit. 'Mary learns Latin and Pau also does it') with the ill-formedness of Cat. "La Maria sap llatí i en Pau també ho fa" (lit. 'Mary knows Latin and Pau also does it'). The contrast has to do with the fact that _aprendre_ 'to learn' is non-stative, whereas _saber_ 'to know' is stative. _Saber_ is like _odiar_, for example: both are stative predicates.

Comment: It seems quite clear that _facere_ in _facere id_ doesn't have the **grammaticalized** status of the English verb _do_ in your example "I hate cod but she doesn't" (or "Peter hates cod, doesn't he?" for that matter). NB: I also pointed out that _do so_ is not exactly the same as _facere id_. So my point here is how to relate the alleged stativity of _odi_ and _amo_ with the non-stativity of _id faciam_.

Comment: @Mitomono; Frankly, I find this Q difficult to follow. Please confirm: "psychological predicates (fear type) are stative"; meaning, a state-of-mind (being in love, in lust) which is an unchanging situation throughout the time frame, under consideration; which, could be a lifetime?

Comment: @Mitomino: Secondly, "translations of "odi" & "amo" ...should ideally incorporate a more agentive component, which is typically missing in "I hate" & "I love,". The agent appears to be absent? In "the girl was bitten by the dog", the dog is an agent because he's doing something to the subject. Here, "I loathe and I lust" for whom--an indirect object? Is it your argument that the agent should be making a presence e.g. "I loathe and lust for she who tortures me"--sort of thing? This would require a revamp of the poem which could upset the spirit of Catallus and his, still-living, acolytes?

Comment: @tony. As for the first question, yes, the time frame of stative verbs like the ones of _fear/timere_ class can be a "lifetime" but this is not necessary (NB: the lexical-aspectual classification of predicates is not based on world knowledge but on our **linguistic** knowledge of them. E.g., cf. the**linguistic** definition of state: http://web.ku.edu/~pyersqr/Ling331/Kearns9.htm ).

Comment: @tony. As for your second question, the point is that _hate_ and _love_ are stative predicates that are **not** agentive. This makes them incompatible with being reassumed by means of an agentive expression like _do it/facere id_. At least this is impossible in Romance languages like Catalan or Spanish (and Hebrew); see above. In contrast, to the extent that "I loathe and I lust" are more agentive than "I hate and I love", the former would be a more appropriate translation of _Odi and amo_ (in THIS context where all (?) verbs of the 1st verse are more agentive than the ones of the 2nd verse).

Comment: @Mitomino: That one stative predicate ("I loathe and I lust") is more compatible with the verbs of 1st verse, I understand; but, why is this more agentive than "I hate and I love": all are powerful emotions; all can generate crazy/ dangerous behaviour from rape to suicide? In English "loathe" & "hate" are used interchangeably; the difference can only be marginal--how does this affect things? Tried to find examples of agentive verbal phrase, "facere id"; pronoun of choice appears to be "hoc": "ubi hoc fecit"; "cum hoc fecisset". The prohibition with 2nd person of perfect-subjunctive,

Comment: @Mitomino: Continuing: "ne feceris illud, Marce" = "Don't do that, Marcus!" Of course "illud" is equivalent to "id": former, illud = "that" (something yonder); id = "that" (something close). Catallus may have used "id" to metaphorically, mentally or physically show how close (personally, intimately) all of this was to his soul. To put stative verbs with a non-stative agentive-verbal expression, he would have called "poetic license". Maddening, when translating, to see how the great Roman writers conferred meanings upon words that are not included in dictionaries!

Comment: @tony: I'm not a native speaker of English but as for Romance languages like Catalan and Spanish, it sounds quite odd to reassume stative psychological verbs with "to do it". To the extent that the alleged stative verb acquires a more physical component (and becomes less "psychological", so to speak), one can predict that the test of _facere id_ is better. Quite probably, Catullus coerced the meaning of _odisse_ and _amare_ and wanted them to be more agentive in THIS context (see Arkins 2011 above), this being allowed as a sort of "poetic license", as you say.

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you. Hate to "mither"; but, could yourself, please, confirm the Q: why is "I loathe and lust"  more agentive than "I hate and I love"? Is it that, here, "agentive" means "destructive"/ "dangerous"; less "psychological", as you said; that is--less a state-of-mind, more a violent reaction?

Comment: I understand that to the extent that "I loathe and lust" involve a more physical meaning (or at I least I deduced this from Arkins 2011) , they can be taken as a bit more agentive than "I hate and love". Perhaps with "lust" it is more clear but I don't know since I'm not a native speaker of English.